# jquery auto width function doesn't work when dynamically created ul>li by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to stackoverflow and this is my first question here. Please overlook if I made any mistake.
Here is my problem : First I create jquery to define auto width to list.

```
(function(){
        var items = $('.main-menu>li');
        var maxitems = items.length; //items.length;
        var current = items[0];
        $('.main-menu li').css('width', (100 / maxitems | 0) + '%');
})();
```

Then I write these codes to create li element dynamically. But unfortunately this newly created li items are not taking auto width functionality that I previously coded.

```
function topMenu() {
  document.getElementById('addTopMenu').onclick = addTopMenu;
}

function addTopMenu() {
  var el = document.getElementById("main-menubar");
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  node.id = "main-menubar";
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.innerText = data = prompt("Type A Name For New Menu","");
  var value = prompt("Type The href Of The Menu","");
  link.setAttribute("href", value);
  node.appendChild(link);
  el.appendChild(node);
}
```

Please help me out this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: why not use flexbox to space things evenly, then you won't have this jquery problem, otherwise just put the initial js code into a function and call that after on document load and when you add a li dynamically

Comment: Yape I can do it with css Pete but it's my project work to make it done with javascript. When I write li manually initial function works fine. But when the li is created dynamically it ignores the first function. I am a beginner in javascript. So I may be fail to make my question obvious.